# Two persons working on same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, spatial-database, version-control

We are two people who need to edit on the same layer in QGIS. For example one of us will edit locally, the other one via a server connection.

Comment: Hi Vignesh! First of all, are both persons going to edit the layer(which may be difficult) or is at least one of them going just to read the layer? If both persons are going to edit it, what kind of data storage are you using? (Two persons reading the same layer is never a problem)

Comment: Is your layer file based or in a PostGIS database? And what exactly do you mean by 'work'?

Comment: If you want both persons to edit the layer, you probably have to use a server based database as PostGIS. Filebased databases as Geopackage are not suitable for streaming (remote access) and afaik also not ideal for access by several users at once. Filebased data formats without database structure are even less apt to be used by several users at once.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

For simple use with not too many features, there is a useful tool called GooGIS which is a plugin to QGIS. The data is held in Google Drive, you login and authenticate by your Google Account. It manages edits on a per row basis apparently. It is a little buggy to get running, esp on Windows, but might meet your needs perfectly. https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/gdrive_provider/ and https://github.com/enricofer/gdrive_provider